# How to update flutter_sodium libary to sodium_libs libary?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I would like update my libary flutter_sodium 0.2.0 to sodium_libs latest version.
This is my code:
`var keyPair = Sodium.cryptoBoxkeypair();         while (uint8ListToString(keyPair.pk).contains(String.fromCharCode(0)) ||             uint8ListToString(keyPair.sk).contains(String.fromCharCode(0))) {           keyPair = Sodium.cryptoBoxKeypair();         }`

The sodium_libs libary doesn't have cryptoBoxKeypair() method.I need help  I don't know how to change this code to make it compatible with the soidum_libs libary.

I tried use Sodium.runIsolated() or Box.keyPair() but is error Instance member 'runIsolated' can't be accessed using static access. I am beginner in Flutter.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.