# How update flutter_sodium 0.2.0 to sodium_libs?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

My code:
`/// Generates a random secret key and a corresponding public key. var receiver=Sodium.cryptoBoxKeypair();`

In sodium_libs doesn't have cryptoboxKeypair() method.
I'm trying use this: var receiver = Box.keyPair();
But is error: Instance member 'keyPair' can't be accessed using static access.

How can I generate random secret key and a a corresponding public key in sodium_libs?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of your earlier question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76953408/how-to-update-flutter-sodium-libary-to-sodium-libs-libary

Comment: Have you tried `Box().keyPair()`?

Comment: yes but it is error: The class 'Box' doesn't have an unnamed constructor.
Try using one of the named constructors defined in 'Box'.

Answer (score 0):

When using `sodium_libs`, see the example and usage of the package.

In your `main` be sure to initialize as follows:

```
// when used before rendering the first frame:
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

final sodium = await SodiumInit.init();
// You now have a Sodium instance, see sodium package to continue
```

Now, when you want to use a `sodium` method, so that package's usage, for example:

```
 final pair = sodium.crypto.box.keyPair(); // note that sodium is the object returned above
```